# Joomla - Send grid configuration issue

Tags: joomla

We are developing Joomla website and have to do Send grid configurations. We have set everything as per guided in official site.

We are getting following issue when sending the email from joomla backend.
"SMTP Error! Could not connect to SMTP host."

Comment: have you added the SMTP details to the global configuration parameters in the Joomla backend? If so, ensure they are all correct.

Comment: SendmailPath : /usr/sbin/sendmail
SMTP Authentication : Yes
SMTP Security : SSL
SMTP Port : 465

Here are the settings.
SMTP Host smtp.sendgrid.net

Comment: have you ensured the password is correct?

Comment: Yes. We have verified that everything is fine

Answer (score 1):

this is most likely host-related. First make sure your component is not the issue try sending an email from the user manager.

- If it goes through, then your component is not using Joomla configuration properly
- If it doesn't (which I would expect) it's just a problem with your server configuration,

check firewall, spam settings, try to send email from the command line...

Comment: This is what I would recommend as well.  If you're still having issues, contact SendGrid support for more help. http://support.sendgrid.com/